# How to design angular service class for REST service with optional query params

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

I have a REST service which returns all the students.

```
URL : rest/students
```

I can add optional parameters to it like,

```
URL : rest/students?department=1001&valid=true
```

For this use case I have created an angular service,

```
angular.module('app.student').
     factory('StudentService',StudentService);

StudentService.$inject = ['$http','ENV_CONSTANTS'];
function StudentService($http,ENV_CONSTANTS){
     var service = {
         getAllStudents : getAllSTudents,
         getValidStudents : getValidStudents,
         getValidStudentByDepartment : getValidStudentByDepartment 
     };

     return service;

     function getAllStudents(){
          return $http.get(ENV_CONSTANTS.baseUrl+'/students');
     }

     function getValidStudents(){
          return $http.get(ENV_CONSTANTS.baseUrl+'/students?valid=true');
     }

     function getValidStudentByDepartment (departmentId){
              return $http.get(ENV_CONSTANTS.baseUrl+
              '/students?valid=true&departmentId'+departmentId);
         }
    }
```

But I feel that it's not a good design, because for every query param or the combination of query param I need to create a method. Could anybody suggest a proper way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The url building ( baseUrl + "/my-suffix" ) is not of bad design imho.

The query parameter building is. `$http.get` can take a map for this :

```
$http.get(myUrl, { params : myParamMap })
```

I.E :

```
$http.get(myUrl, { params : { valid : true, departmentId : "myDepId" } });
```

This allow parameter building to be easier and prettier

You could also pre-generates your url constants :

```
var STUDENT_URL = ENV_CONSTANTS.baseUrl+'/students';
```

to avoid the url building in each of your methods

```
$http.get(STUDENT_URL, { params : myParams });
```

Which would be way more maintainable

Then you could factorize :

```
function performStudentCall(paramMap) {
    return $http.get(STUDENT_URL, { params : paramMap });
}
```

to be able to call :

```
function getValidStudentByDepartment (departmentId) {
    return performStudentCall({ valid : true, departmentId : departmentId });
}
```

here you would have one service method per action, which is the correct approach, while keeping only one method to performs all http calls.

Comment: Thanks for your time and information. So if paramMap is null here will it get ignored automatically?

Comment: I'd say yes, but you can fireproof in the performStudentCall to check if paramMap != null to be sure

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function and pass the query param object with field value pair in function parameter.

something like

```
function getStudents(queryParamObject){
          return $http.get(ENV_CONSTANTS.baseUrl+'/students', { params : queryParamObject });
}
```

Comment: krish beat me to it. The only other thing I'd suggest is make the endpoint, students in this case, a required parameter of the function.